# On delete cascade to table

Tags: mysql, cascade

How can I add on delete cascade to this table creation script? id_fk comes from mytable table.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ip` (

  `ip_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `id_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  `ip_add` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ip_id`),

  KEY `id_fk` (`id_fk`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `ip`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_mytable` FOREIGN KEY (`id_fk`) REFERENCES `mytable` (`id`)   
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add a [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and specify what to do and when.

```
 ALTER TABLE ip
    ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
        FOREIGN KEY index_name(id_fk)
            REFERENCES other_table(other_column_name)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

You can include the constraint directly in the table definition:

```
FOREIGN KEY index_name(id_fk)
    REFERENCES other_table(other_column_name)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: This is foreign key KEY id_fk (id_fk)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES other_table(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE C' at line 4

Comment: I corrected that but you have to come up with a constraint name and an index name.

Comment: It would also be useful if you show me your other table's structure. Because you have to change `other_table` to the name of your other table and `other_column_name` to the name of the referred column.